# Duplicating PostgreSQL database on one server to MySQL database on another server

Tags: mysql, postgresql, backup

I have a PostgreSQL database with 4-5 tables (some of those have more than 20 million rows). i have to replicate this entire database onto another machine. However, there I have MySQL (and for some reason cannot install PostgreSQL) on that machine.

The database is static and is not updated or refreshed. No need to sync between the databases once replication is done. So basically, I am trying to backup the data.

There is a utility called *pg_dump* which will dump the contents onto a file. I can zip and ftp this onto the other server. However, I do not have `psql` on the other machine to reload this into a database. Is there a possibility that `mysql` might parse and decode this file into a consistent database?

`Postgres` is version 9.1.9 and `mysql` is version 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.

Is there any other *simple* way to do this without installing any services?

Comment: I would go for a solution where you dump the data to a "delimited" text file format (e.g. CSV) and then import it on the  MySQL side (e.g. using LOAD DATA)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks for the suggestion. Found "copy" command which may be used to dump a table as a CSV. I can then reload it in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you consider "simple". Since it's only a small number of tables, the way I'd do it is like this:

1. dump individual tables with pg_dump -t table_name --column-inserts
2. edit the individual files, change the schema definitions to be compatible with mysql (e.g. using auto_increment instead of serial, etc. : like this: http://www.xach.com/aolserver/mysql-to-postgresql.html only in reverse)
3. load the files into the mysql utility like you would any other mysql script.

If the files are too large for step #2, use the -s and -a arguments to pg_dump to dump the data and the schema separately, then edit only the schema file and load both files in mysql.